# Use Puppet facts (Facter) inside a shell script

Tags: shell, puppet, facter

I am writing a shell script to download a `version.txt` file from a AWS S3 bucket.

In the shell script, I need to use a Puppet Facter value (e.g. `env_name` and `product_name`). How can I fetch those Facter values inside of my shell script?

Answer (score 3):

Run `facter env_name` to retrieve the value:

```
env_name=$(facter env_name)
echo $env_name
```

If it's a fact that comes from a Puppet module (via pluginsync), add the `-p` argument:

```
env_name=$(facter -p env_name)
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent to this using the new syntax (`puppet fact ...`) compared to the deprecated syntax (`facter --puppet ...`)? `facter --help` says "-p, --puppet                     (Deprecated: use `puppet facts` instead)"